# Perform a GM_xmlhttpRequest before and after loading a page on Firefox

Tags: javascript, linux, firefox, greasemonkey, userscripts

I'm at vacation and the price for the internet connection in my hotel is crazy.

The network traffic is blocked until a valid username/password pair is sent to http://an.internal.address/login using an http post request.

However, they give the users the possibility to switch off the connection by visiting http://an.internal.address/logout

I want to maximize the duration of my 1h internet ticket by automating the following with Greasemonkey:

1. http post data "username=MY_USERNAME&password=MY_PASSWORD" to http://an.internal.address/login
2. load a page with my browser
3. http get http://an.internal.address/logout

I use Firefox 30 and I think Greasemonkey can actually do that. However, I'm at my first try at writing a user script: it works partially.

It seems that login() isn't called at all, and logout doesn't perform the GM_xmlhttpRequest, because no alert() containing the response is issued.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        test
// @namespace   leonixyz
// @version     0.1
// @description Calls shell script once a page has been loaded or leaved
// @match       http://*/*
// @match       https://*/*
// @copyright   leonixyz
// ==/UserScript==

function login() {
    GM_xmlhttpRequest({
       method: "POST",
       url: "http://1.1.1.1/login",
       data: "username=DE14945&password=VBJEETYN&dst=&popup=true",
       onload: function(response) {
          alert(response.responseText);
       }
    });
}

function logout() {
    GM_xmlhttpRequest({
       method: "GET",
       url: "http://1.1.1.1/logout",
       onload: function(response) {
           alert(response.responseText);
       }
    });
}

window.addEventListener("unload", login);
window.addEventListener("load", logout);
```

Comment: `onload` and `onunload`, but `onunload` is not reliable yet.

Comment: You're on vacation; throw away the gizmos and enjoy a few days off the grid! ... Anyway, what you want is probably possible with just Greasemonkey alone, but there's no way for us to see details that may be crucial or to test solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: all GM_functions() needs to be declared into the header, after a @grant meta tag. 
If you plan to stay for vacation in the the Hotel Delfin, near Poreč, Croatia, buy at the reception a 1h internet ticket and enjoy the following script (sometimes you have to connect manually, expecially when opening new tabs, but the disconnect definetely works and saves your precious connection time):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Laguna Wifi hack
// @namespace   leonixyz
// @version     0.1
// @description connect/disconnect automatically when browsing
// @match       http://*/*
// @match       https://*/*
// @exclude     http://1.1.1.1/*
// @copyright   leonixyz
// @grant       GM_xmlhttpRequest
// ==/UserScript==

function login() {
    GM_xmlhttpRequest({
       method: "POST",
       url: "http://1.1.1.1/login",
       data: "username=MY_USERNAME&password=MY_PASSOWRD"
    });
}

function logout() {
    GM_xmlhttpRequest({
       method: "GET",
       url: "http://1.1.1.1/logout"
    });
}

window.addEventListener("beforeunload", login);
window.addEventListener("load", logout);
```